# Easing function of Microsoft office 2013 animations

Tags: animation, windows-8, easing, easing-functions, gui-design

Making use of animations, had became easy and straightforward in designing GUI for almost all platforms. But selection of easing function dramatically affect the user experience, and I think the easing function used in MS Office 2013 (and probably windows 8 in general), is really cool! Does anyone knows what it is?